# Cakephp bug : in paginator joins generated query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, pagination

When below code below it generate query with single quote in join query

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                  'table' => 'businesses_categories',
                  'alias' => 'BusinessesCategory',
                  'type' => 'LEFT',
                  'conditions' => array('Business.id' => 'BusinessesCategory`.`business_id'),
                ),
                array(
                  'table' => 'categories',
                  'alias' => 'Category',
                  'type' => 'LEFT',
                  'conditions' => array('BusinessesCategory.category_id' => 'Category.id'),
              ),
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Category.id' => 24),
            'limit' => 10
        );

        $businesses = $this->Paginator->paginate('Business');
```

I have added query that's generated by above paginator query. query works fine, when i use  ON (`Business`.`id` = `BusinessesCategory`.`business_id`) instead of  ON (`Business`.`id` = 'BusinessesCategory`.`business_id')

how do i fix this. so, it does not include single quote on values

```
SELECT `Business`.`id`,
       `Business`.`state`,
       `Business`.`slug`,
       `Business`.`city`,
       `Business`.`suburb`,
       `Business`.`user_id`,
       `Business`.`business_name`,
       `Business`.`business_address`,
       `Business`.`business_postal`,
       `Business`.`business_postal_id`,
       `Business`.`business_phone`,
       `Business`.`business_phone1`,
       `Business`.`business_phone2`,
       `Business`.`business_email`,
       `Business`.`business_website`,
       `Business`.`business_details`,
       `Business`.`business_openinghours`,
       `Business`.`business_service`,
       `Business`.`business_addtionalinfo`,
       `Business`.`business_lat`,
       `Business`.`business_lng`,
       `Business`.`identity`,
       `Business`.`status`
FROM `yuldicom`.`businesses` AS `Business`
LEFT JOIN `yuldicom`.`businesses_categories` AS `BusinessesCategory` ON (`Business`.`id` = 'BusinessesCategory`.`business_id')
LEFT JOIN `yuldicom`.`categories` AS `Category` ON (`BusinessesCategory`.`category_id` = 'Category.id')
WHERE `Category`.`id` = 24 LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go :--

```
    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'joins' => array(
            array(
              'table' => 'businesses_categories',
              'alias' => 'BusinessesCategory',
              'type' => 'LEFT',
              'conditions' => array('Business.id=BusinessesCategory.business_id'),
            ),
            array(
              'table' => 'categories',
              'alias' => 'Category',
              'type' => 'LEFT',
              'conditions' => array('BusinessesCategory.category_id=Category.id'),
          ),
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Category.id' => 24),
        'limit' => 10
    );

    $businesses = $this->Paginator->paginate('Business');
```

Comment: I ahve fixed it, ('`BusinessesCategory`.`category_id`=`Category`.`id`')